# Updating a table with over 25,000 entries

Tags: mysql, batch-processing

I want to try to set two values in a SQL table based on a search in another table. My query is the following:

```
UPDATE $postmeta
SET meta_key = '_bbps_topic_status',
    meta_value = '1'
    WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM $posts 
    WHERE post_type='topic'
   )
```

I want to do this for the entire table of 25,148 rows, but I get a memory error even after increasing all the limits on the server. I know that MySQL doesn't allow you to batch operations in groups of, say 500, but is there any way to write a script that would divide this operation up into smaller chunks?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The query includes a date range:

```
UPDATE $postmeta
SET meta_key = '_bbps_topic_status',
    meta_value = '1'
    WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM $posts 
    WHERE post_type='topic'
    AND DATE_SUB(
        CURDATE(),
        INTERVAL 30 DAY
        ) <= post_date
   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join method and an index on `post_id` from `$postmeta` table  will be helpful

```
UPDATE $postmeta  m
JOIN $posts p ON(p.ID = m.post_id )
SET m.meta_key = '_bbps_topic_status',
    m.meta_value = '1'
 WHERE p.post_type='topic'
 AND p.post_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Note you are using a sub query which will run for each row instead use join also add index on your date column to improve the performance of your query

Comment: Hey Khalid-- I added a more complex query because I couldn't figure out how to include that in the JOIN command you're using.

Comment: @RoboRob what is the purpose of using `DATE_SUB` part while you are not comparing the result of this expression ?

Comment: I'm trying to get all posts of the type 'topic' older than 30 days. When I ran that in a SELECT statement, it seemed to do what I wanted.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the comparison is <= post_date